# Building FLANN with Cmake fails

Tags: cmake, flann, sles

I am trying to build FLANN libraries in order to build PCL library afterwards.

I get an error while using CMake to compile the source.
I guess I am missing something very basic. Since I can't find a compiled library for my system I have to build it myself.

With the command

```
~/flann-1.8.4-src/build> cmake ..
```

I get

```
CMake Error at src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:86 (add_library):
No SOURCES given to target: flann
CMake Error at src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:32 (add_library):
No SOURCES given to target: flann_cpp
```

This happens with flann 1.8.4 and 1.9.1 on a SLES11 operating system.

Any hint?

Here a complete transcription of what cmake says:

```
-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found     version "")
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:76 (message):
  hdf5 library not found, some tests will not be run


-- Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:115 (message):
  gtest library not found, some tests will not be run


-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE
CMake Warning at src/matlab/CMakeLists.txt:79 (message):
  Cannot find MATLAB or Octave instalation.  Make sure that the 'bin'
  directory from the MATLAB instalation or that mkoctfile is in PATH


hdf5 library not found, not compiling flann_example.cpp
-- Could NOT find LATEX (missing: LATEX_COMPILER)
-- Install prefix: /usr/local
-- Build type: RelWithDebInfo
-- Building C bindings: ON
-- Building python bindings: ON
-- Building matlab bindings: ON
-- Building CUDA library: OFF
-- Using OpenMP support: ON
-- Using MPI support: OFF
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:86 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: flann


CMake Error at src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:32 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: flann_cpp
-- Build files have been written to: ~/flann-1.8.4-src/build
```

Comment: The project's `CMakeLists.txt` uses `add_library(flann_cpp SHARED "")`. They want to build a header-only library, but in CMake building the library without sources is not a right way. BTW, they already has a [bug report](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/issues/369).

Comment: Thank you, the bug report gave me the right workaround!

Answer (score 5):

In your flann dir
run

```
touch src/cpp/empty.cpp
```

In src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt
replace

```
add_library(flann_cpp SHARED "") and add_library(flann SHARED "")
```

with

```
add_library(flann_cpp SHARED empty.cpp) and add_library(flann SHARED empty.cpp)
```

Hope this helps :)
[link](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann/issues/369), thanks to the comment by Tsyvarev